# Rabbitmq cluster, How to find a node from queue or exchange name?

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm new in rabbitmq, I can't find any document that is related with algorithm or structure of inter-node message passing.

What is the algorithm finding a node from a queue name in a different node in a cluster?
I'm considering how much overhead is in inter-node message passing of cluster.

If you have any document related with this, please leave its link.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm considering how much overhead is in inter-node message passing of
> cluster.

More than likely, you don't have to worry about this.

> What is the algorithm finding a node from a queue name in a different node in a cluster?

You want to find modules that implement the `rabbit_queue_master_locator` behavior that is defined [here](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-common/blob/4229aaeca032971cf693035e77b23b5b08f047aa/src/rabbit_queue_master_locator.erl). The `queue_master_location/1` function in a module that implements this behavior is called to find the node that should be the master for a queue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are in the rabbitMq group. Impressed. Because of I'm not expert in erlang so I can't find any algorithm finding a node. In your link.
Isn't the link you gave me just adding/removing function? I'm searching about "How to select a node for propagate a message from queue or exchange name.

Comment: Additionally, I think this overhead would be important, because MQ cluster can be larger, if there is one queue per user.

Comment: Nodes are not derived from queue or exchange names. The source code to which I linked is how a node is selected for a new queue. If you want to know this information as RabbitMQ is running, query the HTTP API to determine it. Finally, clusters of more than 5 nodes are not recommended as adding nodes makes RabbitMQ slower due to the mesh of communication between them. Clusters are for fault-tolerance.

Comment: Oh, 5 nodes was recommended max. By the way, I'm not talking about for a new queue.
It is the situation, there are queues and sending a message to one of queues through a node. then, a node should find the node which the queue is in to send message.

Comment: Anyway, If there are more than 5 nodes, The communication cost would be expensive.

Comment: "then, a node should find the node which the queue is in to send message" - OK I see. A queue is represented by an Erlang process, and Erlang gives you the ability to communicate with any process on any node in your cluster, transparently. What RabbitMQ does is store the name of a queue with its process information in an internal database (called Mnesia). Then, when a queue process needs to be found by queue name, this database is queried.